# How to use set method of a different class in java?

Tags: java, class, getter-setter

How can I set the value of a parameter of class `A` in class `B` using the `setvarA` method of class `A`?

```
public class A{

String varA;
public String getvarA() {
        return varA;
    }
public void setvarA(String varA) {
        this.varA=varA;
    }
}

public class B{

String name = "abc";
A objA = new A();
objA.setvarA(name) ; ## THIS LINES THROWS AN ERROR

}
```

The error is:

```
Syntax error on token "name", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token and Syntax error on token(s), misplaced constructs
```

Comment: Missed `;`  in the end?


objA.setvarA(name);

Comment: Also missing `;` after "abc" and `this.varA=var.A;` should be `this.varA = varA;`

Comment: Please read the language syntax and semantics

Comment: Sorry for the syntax errors.. I typed a sample code here itself.. Didnt wanna confuse wit my actual code.. I'll do the corrections.. But can anyone pls help me with the actual problem???

Comment: The main problem is that the line you're pointing at does not belong to a method, ie. it is not located inside a method definition.

Comment: You need to learn basic of Java before starting coding in java. You cannot call a method in java unless you are inside another method or constructor. The line you were pointing as error should be inside a method or within a constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class A{

    String varA;
    public String getvarA() {
        return varA;
    }
    public void setvarA(String varA) {
        this.varA=varA;
    }
}

class B {
    String name = "abc";
    A objA = new A();

    B() {
        objA.setvarA(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that you only complain about one error.

There are a number of different errors in the code you posted:

- It's `String`, not `string` (case is important)
- In the method `setvarA`, this is wrong: `this.varA = var.A;`, should have been: `this.varA = varA;`
- Forgot a semi-colon after `String name = "abc"`
- Forgot `()` after `new A`: `A objA = new A();`

Comment: Sorry about that.. wanted to put fwd the logic and typed the code here directly and not in a IDE

Answer (score 0):

Revised Code:

```
public class A{

        String varA; //<-String, not string
        public String getVarA() { 
                return varA;
            }
        public void setVarA(String varA) {
                this.varA=varA; //<- var.A not valid
            }
        }

        class B{
          B(){ //<- Need to write this code in a method or constructor
            String name = "abc"; //<- Semi-colon?
            A objA = new A(); //<- what about parenthesis?
            objA.setVarA(name); //<- Semi-colon?
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your class B is not working, because the last line of code is outside a method! (see my answer...)

Comment: Nothing has changed... `objA.setVarA(name);` is still outside a method!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corrected and complete code:

```
public class A{

    String varA;

    public String getvarA() {
        return varA;
    }

    public void setvarA(String varA) {
        this.varA = varA;
    }
}

public class B{

    public B(){
        String name = "abc"
        A objA = new A();
        objA.setvarA(name);
    }
}
```

Both classes must go in separate files, calles A.java and B.java, of course. Add a main method in one of these files, creating B.

Comment: ,downvote for a good answer, that too without giving the reason.

Comment: And another one! WTF!!

Answer (score -1):

It should be `A objA = new A();`

- **By doing this, you are invoking the constructor of class `A` which
  creates the object of class `A` and assigns the reference variable
  `objA` to it**.
- Also, `objA.setvarA(name);`. You missed semicolon here.
- change your `string` to `String`. java is case sensitive.`String` is a class.
- change `this.varA=var.A;` to `this.varA = varA;`
- Missing semi colon here `String name = "abc"`. Change to `String name = "abc";`
- You have put extra semi colon in setter method. Please correct that.
- Also, you need to call the method from some init block or constructor or a method

  `B() {
          objA.setvarA(name);
      }`

Comment: It was not me who downvoted the answer, but I suppose because you did not detect the predominant error. The setter is not called within a method, but on a class field declaration instead.